# MYSQL: select where / and / or with two tables

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get the following SQl working:

```
SELECT * FROM tc_appointment as tcAppointment, tc_message as tcMessage
WHERE tcAppointment.counsellor_id = 502
AND 
(
    (tcAppointment.tc_message_id = tcMessage.id AND tcMessage.marked_read = false AND tcMessage.sender_id != 502)
    OR
    (tcAppointment.cancelled = true AND tcAppointment.cancelled_acknowledged = false)
    OR 
    (tcAppointment.confirmed = false)
);
```

The `tcAppointment.tc_message_id` is null in the only `tc_appointment` entry in the table. I am trying to get it to return as the `counsellor_id = 502` and the second `OR` statment is `true`

I seem to be getting stuck because of the `tc_message as tcMessage` clause and the first `AND` / `OR` statement but I'm not sure why. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Learn about ANSI 92 joins using INNER, LEFT, and RIGHT join syntax. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ or learn the concept of outer joins using the prior to ANSI 92 join.  I believe the notation is `*=` or `=*` or is it `+=` and `=+`... I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Joining the 2 tables and use the 'Where':

```
 SELECT * FROM tc_appointment as tcAppointment 
    LEFT JOIN tc_message as tcMessage 
    ON 
    ((tcAppointment.tc_message_id = tcMessage.id AND tcMessage.marked_read = false AND tcMessage.sender_id != 502)
    OR
        (tcAppointment.cancelled = true AND tcAppointment.cancelled_acknowledged = false)
        OR 
        (tcAppointment.confirmed = false)
) 

    WHERE tcAppointment.counsellor_id = 502
```